# Using XSLT for desired output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following XML

```
<Name>
  <Person>
    <Car>
      <brand>Merc</brand>
    </Car>
    <Car>
      <brand>Merc</brand>
    </Car>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Car>
      <brand>Audi</brand>
    </Car>
  </Person>
</Name>
```

And my desired output is

```
<People>
  <Resident>
   <Number>1</Number>
   <Vehicle>
     <CarNumber>1</CarNumber>
     <CarNumber>2</CarNumber>
  </Vehicle>
 </Resident>
 <Resident>
   <Number>2</Number>
   <Vehicle>
     <CarNumber>3</CarNumber>
   </Vehicle>
 </Resident>
</People>
```

Here please notice that CarNumber is 3 in the second Resident.

I have following XSLT for this

```
<People>    
  <xsl:for-each select="Name/Person">
    <Resident>
      <Number><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></Number>
    </Resident>
    <Vehicle>
      <xsl:for-each select="Car/brand">
        <CarNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/><CarNumber>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Vehicle>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

but I am getting

```
<People>
<Resident>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Vehicle>
        <CarNumber>1</CarNumber>
        <CarNumber>2</CarNumber>
    </Vehicle>
</Resident>
<Resident>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Vehicle>
        <CarNumber>1</CarNumber>
    </Vehicle>
</Resident>
```

Is there anyway I can convert this using XSLT?

Here Instead of 3 as CarNumber I am getting 1.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? -- P.S. Are you sure you want to discard the existing data?

Comment: Edited the question. It might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <People>    
        <xsl:for-each select="Name/Person">
            <Resident>
                <Number><xsl:number/></Number>
            </Resident>
            <Vehicle>
                <xsl:for-each select="Car">
                    <CarNumber><xsl:number level="any"/></CarNumber>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Vehicle>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </People>   
</xsl:template>
```